# How can I make navbar element load in place without sliding?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a header, which includes a navigation section and a logo section. I want the logo to align left and the navigation bar to align right. I've initially done this with float left (for logo) and float right (for navbar), but later decided to use "justify-content: space-between;" for the parent element (#header). (This does not change the nature of the problem.)

The problem when loading this with Chrome is that the header loads as if it is gradually expanding from the right and left edges toward the center. I don't see the same problem in Firefox. After loading it once, I cannot immediately replicate the problem, unless I wait for a few minutes or clear my cache and cookies. Here is the url that I'm experimenting at where you can (hopefully) view the problem:

https://www.omerfyalcin.com/experimental/
./style.css to see the style file.

This is pretty annoying since it prevents the transition between pages from looking smooth. Cannot find a solution despite extensive searching.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sandbox so i cannot reliably try it but it's definitely related to `transition: all 0.4s`. There must be some kind of width change or something in the header and `transition: all` is causing that animation to happen. Make your transition to target more specific behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is probably the reason! I'll try this.